# Cell specifying the running total length

Tags: google-sheets

## Context

Here column `C` contains a running total of the last 5 items from column `B`.

[image]

## Formula

The formula is straightforward:

[image]

## Question

In the above, it's hardcoded for a running total of 5.

What's a good way to have the running total length specified in a separate cell instead of being hardcoded to 5?

I.e. something like this:

[image]

so that the user can easily change the 5 to a 7 to get a running total of the last 7.

## Link to doc

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rDgq-98bmyni715IUStOf8keBntW6D6dAq7sppSHwMo/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited a [copy of your spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eMYXMeyYqfaDXNvi0mtZcq1AHYTBJr2q0mEqENeU-rU/edit?usp=sharing) to get what you wanted.

I hope it fits you well
[image: Modified]

Comment: This is awesome, Daniele! Thank you!

Comment: Daniele, I added an answer with a slightly modified formula that gets the *last 5 lines* instead of the *next 5 lines*. This is based on your answer, with a slightly modified formula. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164698/293007

Comment: Daniele, here's an approach that only uses `OFFSET`:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164926/293007

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by Daniele uses `indirect()` which is a volatile function that hurts spreadsheet performance. It would seem simpler to use `filter()`, like this in cell `C6`:

`=sum( filter( B$2:B, isbetween(row(B$2:B), row(B2), row(B2) + F$1, true, false) ) )`

See the [filter() from row 6](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eMYXMeyYqfaDXNvi0mtZcq1AHYTBJr2q0mEqENeU-rU/edit#gid=1125000366) sheet in Daniele's copy of the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: very good ... only note is that you have not thought about scaling the last lines based on the choice made in F1. Also I was hoping you had found a way to create a formula that would automatically extend across column C.

Comment: Neither of those requirements are specified in the question.

Comment: there is an error ... your formula considers one more event, for example running 5 sums 6 rows instead of 5

Comment: "Neither of those requirements are specified in the question." 
 see the graph of recent weeks: compare the charts of OP, mine and your

Comment: The formula gets as many rows as specified. You can test it with `=filter( B$2:B, isbetween(row(B$2:B), row(B2), row(B2) + F$1, true, false) )`

Comment: So `ROW(B2)` returns `2`. And `ROW(B2) + F$1` returns `7` (assuming `F$1` is set to `5`). And these are relative references so it'll work when the formula is copied down. However... `ROW(B$2:B)` would seemingly always return `2`, which doesn't seem right. 

Yet it works. :-)

Comment: OK... it looks like `FILTER( ... , ISBETWEEN( ..., A, B )` assumes that `...` are ranges.

Comment: doubleunary, here's an approach that only uses `OFFSET`:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164926/293007

Answer (score 0):

The formula that Daniele used in his answer:

```
=If(row()<=COUNTIF($A$1:$A, "<>")-$F$2+1,Sum(indirect("B"&Row()&":B"&Row()+$F$2-1)),)
```

works great for a running total of the *next* set of lines.

In the original example, I was getting a running total of the *last* 5 lines.

So, I've updated the formula as follows to get the last set of lines:

```
= IF( ROW() >= SIZE + 1, SUM(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() - SIZE + 1 & ":" & "B" & ROW())),)
```

I'm using `SIZE` as a named range for the size of the running total.

Link to example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vGd0NUms_kkdk6w3qvHF8EtJY18_e8pAg29isA8Va2k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is unclear if your question has been answered. To give more details regarding the question, [edit the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/164671/edit) instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**OFSET**

Another approach is to simply use `OFFSET`.

**Screenshot**

Here we have a new column, `SUM LAST N`.

The formula references the last `N` values via `OFFSET` and uses `SUM` on those values.

[image]

**Formula**

The formula used for the cell shown in the screenshot is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B6,-($F$1-1),0,$F$1,1))
```

This can then be copied to the rows below.

**Link**

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xknS6V_VCewVR53alCRF7nvI5gGUpovll69FPuY-1p4/edit?usp=sharing) to the example.